# SetState() not working during IconButton onPressed in Flutter

Tags: flutter, dart

I register the post id that the user likes to the list and check whether he likes it or not.

According to the result, I want to set icon and color with IconButton in SliverAppBar, but does not work.

The basic structure of my code is like here. I don't know how I could do it differently.

```
class Favorite {
List<String> fav = List<String>();

bool checkFav(String id) => fav.contains(id);

addItemToFav(String id) {
    fav.add(id);
  }

deleteItemToFav(String id) {
    fav.remove(id);
  }
}

class DetailPage extends StatefulWidget {
  final Model blogModel;

  DetailPage({this.blogModel});

  @override
  _DetailPageState createState() => _DetailPageState();
}

class _DetailPageState extends State<DetailPage> {
   Favorite favorite = new Favorite();

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    var size = MediaQuery.of(context).size;

    return SafeArea(
      child: Scaffold(
        body: NestedScrollView(
          headerSliverBuilder: (BuildContext context, bool innerBoxIsScrolled) {
            return <Widget>[
              SliverAppBar(
                flexibleSpace: FlexibleSpaceBar(),
                leading: IconButton(),
                actions: [
                  IconButton(
                    onPressed: () {
                      favorite.checkFav(widget.blogModel.id)
                          ? favorite.deleteItemToFav(widget.blogModel.id)
                          : favorite.addItemToFav(widget.blogModel.id);
                      print(favorite.p());
                      setState(
                            () {
                          favorite.checkFav(widget.blogModel.id)
                              ? color = Colors.red
                              : color = Colors.black;
                        },
                      );
                    },

                    icon: Icon(
                        favorite.checkFav(widget.blogModel.id)
                            ? Icons.favorite
                            : Icons.favorite_border,
                        color: color),
                  ),
                ],
              ),
            ];
          },
          body: Container(),
        ),
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

Comment: What is the error / Is there an error message you're receiving from the flutter framework?

Comment: No there is no error output, when I check the data in the list with print() there is no element in the list.

Comment: Why have you added `favorite` before the call to `deleteItemToFav`?  are they defined as `static` methods in the `favorite` class?

Comment: I'm rearranging how my code looks like classes.

Comment: Sorry I don't understand, you are going to edit the question with more code?

Comment: I've updated the question to show how I'm using the codes in my project.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/234230/discussion-between-rohan-thacker-and-semih-yilmaz).

Answer (score 2):

> Favorite favorite = new Favorite();

The reason why it's not working is because your `favorite` instance is being re-created very frequently inside the widget's build() method.

When you call setState (or frequently when Flutter repaints and invokes the build() method), you're basically re-creating a new instance of Favorite.

Hence, why you lose the state of Favorites and why, when you print the list, it's empty.

So you could move the favorite object out like Salih Can showed you, that's one option.

**Unfortunately,** that's also not going to work the moment you add more pages or widgets to this app.

**If you navigate away, you're going to lose the state of that widget** (because the favorite instance was an instance member of the widget's state class, and now the widget has been garbage collected when navigating to a different widget).

This is known as [ephemeral state](https://flutter.dev/docs/development/data-and-backend/state-mgmt/ephemeral-vs-app), while you want app state (i.e. a state that persists no matter where you are in the app).

The simplest way to do this would be to use a [State management solution like Provider](https://flutter.dev/docs/development/data-and-backend/state-mgmt/simple). The linked flutter page shows a very simple way of how to set this up such that, no matter which widget you're inside of, you can be sure that your Favorites will be saved correctly.

Answer (score 1):

`List<String> fav = List<String>();` shouldn't be inside `build()` method, but, inside state class.

Like

```
class _FavoriteWidgetState extends State<FavoriteWidget> {
 List<String> fav = List<String>();
override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
```

Comment: Actually these methods are inside a separate class, not in build() or state.  class Favorite{List<String> fav = List<String>();

bool checkFav(String id) => fav.contains(id);

addItemToFav(String id) {
    fav.add(id);
  }

deleteItemToFav(String id) {
    fav.remove(id);
  }}

Comment: set state works only in statefullWidget. A statefullWidget shoul have a state class.

Comment: I've updated the question to show how I'm using the codes in my project. setstate is already in statefull

Comment: So, you're trying to update a value out of a state class with setState. That's not possible. The state class begins with `class _DetailPageState extends State<DetailPage> {` in your case.

Answer (score 0):

You should move the following line of code above the 'build' method.

```dart
Favorite favorite = new Favorite();
```

It should look like this;

```dart
class _DetailPageState extends State<DetailPage> {
  Favorite favorite = new Favorite();
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    var size = MediaQuery.of(context).size;
....
```

Comment: Really?  "new"?? /me looks at calendar... "yup, still 2021".

Comment: Calm down. :) I took the code from the question so that the person asking can understand it better. This is not our topic.